# Powershell getting values from CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV file which looks like this:

```
  OldEmailAddress,NewEmailAddress
  test@test.com,test2@test.com
```

Power shell code to import the file:

```
 $UserInput = Import-csv "C:\Powershell\UserList.txt" -Delimiter ",";
```

I am going though a foreach loop and trying to write the values but it's print it out as an array in the powershell Window.

```
    foreach ($User in $UserInput) 
    {
     Write-Host $User.OldEmailAddress;
    }
```

The console doesn't display just that filed but the full array.

```
   @{OldEmailAddress=test@test.com; NewEmailAddress=test2@test.com}
```

Why is this occurring?

Comment: Write-host is stringifying your object $user. You will need to use write-host $($user.oldemailaddress) so that your object property pair will be evaluated as an expression. Alternatively, don’t use write-host; use write-output or simply use $user.oldemailaddress alone.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this behavior, are you sure you're executing the exact code as presented here?

Comment: So it works if i just do Write-host $User.oldEmailAddress, but it does if I do something like Write-Host "Testing $User.OldEmailAddress

Comment: when you wrap a dot-referenced object [`$Thing.Property`] in double quotes, the _part before the dot_ is expanded. the dot and the property name are NOT expanded. this is covered rather often since it is such an easy error to make. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for this...

```
"Testing $User.OldEmailAddress
```

...to make it work, do it this way...

```
 $UserInput = Import-Csv 'D:\temp\myemaildata.csv' -Delimiter ','

 ForEach($User in $UserInput)
{$User.OldEmailAddress}
<#
# Results

test@test.com
#>

ForEach($User in $UserInput)
{$User.NewEmailAddress}
<#
# Results

test2@test.com
#>

ForEach($User in $UserInput)
{"$User.OldEmailAddress"}
<#
# Results

@{OldEmailAddress=test@test.com; NewEmailAddress=test2@test.com}.OldEmailAddress
#>

ForEach($User in $UserInput){"$($User.OldEmailAddress)"}
<#
# Results

test@test.com
#>

ForEach($User in $UserInput){"$($User.NewEmailAddress)"}
<#
# Results

test2@test.com
#>
```

... no Write-Host needed since output to the screen is the PowerShell default unless you tell it otherwise. ;-}

Yet, why use that extra loop at all, for example:

```
Import-Csv 'D:\temp\myemaildata.csv' -Delimiter ','
<#
# Results

OldEmailAddress NewEmailAddress
--------------- ---------------
test@test.com   test2@test.com
#>

Import-Csv 'D:\temp\myemaildata.csv' -Delimiter ',' | 
ForEach{$PSItem}

OldEmailAddress NewEmailAddress
--------------- ---------------
test@test.com   test2@test.com


 Import-Csv 'D:\temp\myemaildata.csv' -Delimiter ',' | 
ForEach{$PSItem.OldEmailAddress}
<#
# Results

test@test.com
#>

 Import-Csv 'D:\temp\myemaildata.csv' -Delimiter ',' | 
ForEach{$PSItem.NewEmailAddress}

<#
# Results

test2@test.com
#>
```